# How do I search website's sub-domains for text?

Tags: web-scraping, full-text-search

I am trying to find past exams for my modules in college that are on this website in form of pdfs:

[Link to College Website](http://exampapers.cit.ie/PastExams/Computing/)

The problem is that custom google search engine doesn't work at all and I have to manually go through the pages to find exams I need.
How can I search for text in all directories on this website, so that I get their location, or even better, PDF's of exams I am looking for?

Comment: @M.Douda Hello, should work now, I made some silly mistake typing the url.

Comment: You could download the site with a tool like HTTrack and then search through the files on your local machine?

Comment: @Matt I just did that, thanks for your suggestion.